# Entity Framework Upadating bulk row error: Every derived table must have its own aliases

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I am getting row on the particular criteria in for loop and updating rows one by one by its giving me annoyed exception which i have never seen ever that is: " Every drived table must  have its own alaises"

here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testids.Length; i++)
            {
                int testid = Convert.ToInt32(testids[i]);
                using (var dbContext = new bc_limsEntities1())
                {
                    dc_tpanel_test ob_Test = dbContext.dc_tpanel_test.SingleOrDefault(x => x.testid == testid && x.panelid == panelid);
                    ob_Test.proposedrate = Convert.ToInt32(rates[i]);
                    ob_Test.EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(effectivedates[i], new CultureInfo("ur-Pk", false));

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }

            }
```

**UPDATE: and the respective Table is without Primary Key**

Comment: You might get some hint from here.. (http://forums.asp.net/t/1712705.aspx?Every+derived+table+must+have+its+own+alias+)

Comment: I could'nt find any solution there. . . .

Comment: You can't update any row on EntityFramework without having a Primary key, that's because EF needs an index.